# Click event not always registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dreamweaver, phonegap

I'm trying to make a web app that can be used on mobile.
Below is my nav bar, atop all pages of my site.
The problem is with my hamburger .icon. It can be clicked to dropdown + hide again my nav bar when the screen is resized (ex. on an iPhone). However I seem to have sporadic non-responsiveness from it at times. Almost never works on Safari or iOS. Often doesn't work on Chrome. If I refresh the page a few times or revisit the page, it works, or doesn't, like flipping a coin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
    $(".icon").click(function(){
        $(".topnav").toggleClass("responsive");
    });
    });
```

```css
header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 51px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #52bad5;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #2C9AB7;
      overflow: scroll;
      text-align: left; }

    header a {
      top: 0; }

    header a .logo {
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px 10px;
      position: relative;
      color: #fff;
      top: 0%;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: inline-block;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: left; }

    header .topnav {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      top: -2px;
      left: 0;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px; }
  
    header .icon {
      visibility: hidden;
      height: 31px;
      width: 20px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      z-index: 101;
      cursor: pointer; }
  

    .icon:hover, .topnav:hover {
      background-color: #2C9AB7;
      color: black; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .container header nav {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      width: 100%; }

    header {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #52bad5;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #2C9AB7;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: visible;
      align-content: flex-end; }

    header a .logo {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: left;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
      letter-spacing: normal; }

    header .topnav {
      display: none; }

    header .icon {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      visibility: visible;
      cursor: pointer; }

    header .responsive {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      clear: left;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 70px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #52BAD5;
      text-align: left;
      z-index: 101; } }
```

```html
<header>
    <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none">
    <h1 class="logo">Notes</h1></a>
    <a href="index.html" class="topnav">Home</a
    ><a class="topnav" href="AAA.html">AAA</a
    ><a class="topnav" href="BBB.html">BBB</a
    ><a class="topnav" href="CCC.html">CCC</a
    ><a class="topnav" href="DDD.html">DDD</a
    ><div class="icon" style="cursor: pointer">&#9776;</div>
    </header>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TMori7/nn6ofm3s/

Thanks for the time.

Comment: By adding alert("You clicked the button"); to my code I notice that it isnt a problem with .click event but with the whole .js file.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It's working fine for me on chrome using what you have provided. Are you getting any errors in console? If there are other problems in your .js file, can you provide more of the code?